# Polymer computed binding doesn't get recalculated on update

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I have a `dom-repeat` template that generates table rows, where one of the row cells contains a button, that I want to get disabled when the row value is of certain value. So my component has this code, which uses a computed binding to set the value of the button's `disabled` property:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{list}}" as="ticket">
    <tr class$="{{ticket.status}}">
        <td class="actions">
            <paper-icon-button icon="add" on-tap="incTickets"
                disabled="{{noAvailableTickets(ticket)}}">
            </paper-icon-button>
        </td>
        <td>[[ticket.amount]]</td>
        <td>[[ticket.event.title]]</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

And in my code I have this method:

```
noAvailableTickets : function(ticket) {
    return ticket.event.available_tickets <= 0;
}
```

I can see that the computed binding method is called when the list is first created, once for each item.

Then when I update items, like this:

```
this.set('list.' + ind + '.amount', newamount);
```

The computed binding is not recalcuated, and the method is not called again, even though I can see the value actually change in the `ticket.amount` display in the template.

The [Polymer Data Binding entry in the developer's guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html) has this to say about computed bindings:

> the [...] property is bound to the return value of `computeFullName`, which is recalculated whenever first or last changes. [`first` and `last` are the declared arguments for `computeFullName`]

So under the assumption that the computed binding is not aware of the correlation between the object value, its `amount` property and how other logic uses this to update the `available_tickets` property, I've tried to add a `notifyPath` command with the full updated object, like this:

```
this.notifyPath('list.' + displayId, ticket);
```

But that didn't seem to have any effect. What am I missing?

Comment: I know this has been already answered but have you considered using `this.push('path', value)` instead of `this.set`?

Comment: `push` adds to the array, but I don't want to add another item, just update the existing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect `notifyPath` isn't triggering an update in your case because of [its dirty check](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/677f10c/src/standard/notify-path.html#L97). That is, `list[0]` and `ticket` refer to the same instance (despite the fact that the instance's property has changed), so it's not considered "dirty".

My [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qunagay/edit?html,output) experiment demonstrates that setting `list[0]` to a modified clone indeed triggers an update.

```js
attached: function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var copy = this.list[0].clone();
    copy.amount = 'FREE';
    this.set('list.0', copy);
  }.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

But that's probably not the best way to accomplish this.

According to Polymer [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding), to trigger the computed binding whenever a `ticket` subproperty changes, you would use `ticket.*` in your binding:

```html
<paper-icon-button  disabled="{{noAvailableTickets(ticket.*)}}">
```

```js
Polymer({
  ...
  noAvailableTickets: function(change) {
    var ticket = change.base;
    return ticket.event.available_tickets <= 0;
  }
});
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/japehad/edit?html,output).